# pip install via Jupyter Notebook vs Command Prompt

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

What is the difference between installing library via `python -m pip install XXXX` under Window's `cmd prompt` versus running `pip install XXXX` within Juypter Notebook?

I don't know the mechanics and I'm hoping to better understand this... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when you are not using any virtual environment control and there is only one python install in your system, these two shall behavior the same.

after you install the XXX package, there is no need to install again next time your run your notebook.

When you are using like anaconda, then you have to be careful, where the XXX package is installed to. This is based on which active virtual environment your are running with, then the XXX package will be install in that environment.